# Spring fox reponse with 500 when Java melody is integrated

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, java-melody

Spring fox swagger UI was working fine but when i integrated java melody swagger UI responded with 500 response

Answer (score 0):

Integrating spring boot starter java melody dependency has the issue using java melody core and adding java melody configuration resolve the issue.